# How to give newly opened tab in Internet Explorer as reference to the Document Variable in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to fetch a detail from webpage using Excel Macro. When I click a button in the web page, It opens a new tab, there I will have the detail to be fetched. But my macro is clicking the button in the current web page but it is not going to next newly opened tab.

```
Option Explicit

Sub connectToClarity()

    Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim webDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim webElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim webElements As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "https://intranet.zzzzzzz.com.au/wbg/tools-and-resources/systems/clarity"

    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Loop

    Set webDoc = ie.Document
    Set webElement = webDoc.getElementById("input-keyword")
    webElement.Value = "Clarity"

    Set webElements = webDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")

    For Each webElement In webElements
        If webElement.getAttribute("className") = "btn btn-primary hidden-xs" Then
            webElement.Click
            Exit For
        End If

    Next webElement

    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Loop

    Set webDoc = ie.Document
    Set webElements = webDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")

    Debug.Print webElements.Length
    For Each webElement In webElements
    Debug.Print webElement.innerText

    If webElement.getAttribute("id") = "timeadmin.editTimesheet" Then
        webElement.Click
        Exit For
    End If

    Next webElement

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, might I suggest that you open the link through your code instead of opening the site with a simulated button press?

Comment: If I try to open that link directly, It takes me to different page. that is why I am forced to simulate a button press on the web page so I can navigate to the required web page.